# How to call a Polymer dialog from inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I always fight with Javascript scopes.

I'm trying to show a loading dialog when waiting for a JSON response, like this:

```
          toQueueRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (toQueueRequest.readyState === 4 && toQueueRequest.status === 200) {
              this.$.processingDialog.close();
              this.$.confirmDialog.open();
          } else if (toQueueRequest.readyState === 4){
            this.$.processingDialog.close();
            this.$.errorMsg="Ha ocurrido un error!"
            this.$.errorDialog.open();
          }
      };
      //var data = JSON.stringify({"RestoCode": window.location.pathname, "Fingerprint": this.finger});
      if (this.sector == "Cualquiera") {this.sector = null;};
      var data = JSON.stringify({"RestoCode": restoCode, "Fingerprint": finger, "PhoneNumber": this.cellno, "PersonalName": this.name, "QuantityPeople": this.pas, "SectorId": this.sector});
      toQueueRequest.send(data);

      this.$.reviewDialog.close();
      this.$.processingDialog.open();
```

However, when inside the onreadystatechange function, this.$.ProcessingDialog isn't defined.

How do I call it from inside?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really about Polymer itself, it's a pretty common question about scoping. The real issue here is that inside your callback `this` doesn't refer to your component, but it's a reference for that function. The most common way to work around this has been for a lot of time to back up your context in another variable. So before your callback you would do something like

```
var that = this;
```

And inside your function you would use this other variable, so

```
this.$.processingDialog.close();
```

becomes

```
that.$.processingDialog.close();
```

Alternatively, depending on your build process or the browsers you want to support, if you can use ES6, [the arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax doesn't create a new `this`, so you could just change

```
toQueueRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // ..
}
```

to

```
toQueueRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: @IgnacioNachoParravicini you are welcome, glad to hear that :)